# What is the correct way to format this VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an excel document which will auto fill the date in column A whenever something is entered into an adjacent row. I found a similar answer online:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Updated by Extendoffice 2017/10/12

    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Target.Count = 1) Then
        If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing) Then _
            Target.Offset(0, -1) = Date

        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("B:B"))

        If (Not xRg Is Nothing) Then
            For Each xCell In xRg
                xCell.Offset(0, -1) = Date
            Next
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This makes an the adjacent column autofill the date. Another answer was given in the comments section, which is exactly the function I am after. Dut due to the formatting of the comment section, its indents are not there:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Updated by Extendoffice 20190924

Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
Dim xInt As Integer

On Error Resume Next
If (Target.Count = 1) Then
     If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:N")) Is Nothing) Then
          Application.EnableEvents = False
          xInt = Target.Row
          Me.Range("A" & xInt).Value = Date
          Application.EnableEvents = True
     End If
End If

End Sub
```

How should this be written properly?

Comment: indentation is not important to the running of VBA code. Voting to close as POB.

Comment: When the edit answers the inquiry, then it's no longer an appropriate question.

Answer (score 0):

#### Generic Rule

The number of indents signifies how deeply the relevant lines of code are nested. An extra tab / 4 spaces should be applied for every additional layer of nesting.

#### Helpful Formatting Tools

Several websites out there will automatically do the formatting for you such as:

> http://www.vbindent.com/?indent

#### Answer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Updated by Extendoffice 20190924
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    Dim xInt As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Target.Count = 1) Then
        If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:N")) Is Nothing) Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            xInt = Target.Row
            Me.Range("A" & xInt).Value = Date
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: More general: every _code block_ requires one indentation. A code block is the code of a function or sub, if/else statement, loop (for, while, repeat, do) and with statement.